# Scrolling of ListView getting disabled

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a LinearLayout which contains an image and a ListView. In my code I'm trying to set the layout params of the LinearLayout. Unfortunately, when I do that I'm no longer able to scroll in my ListView. Here are the relevant snippets:

```
private class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {

    private final View mContent;

    private final int mStartHeight;
    private final int mDeltaHeight;

    public ExpandAnimation(int _startHeight, int _endHeight, View _content) {
        mStartHeight = _startHeight;
        mDeltaHeight = _endHeight - _startHeight;
        mContent = _content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mContent.getLayoutParams());
        lp.height = (int) (mStartHeight + mDeltaHeight * interpolatedTime);
        mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
        if(interpolatedTime == 1.0f) {
            lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mListLayout.getLayoutParams());
            View mainLayout = mActivity.findViewById("id goes here");
            lp.height = mainLayout.getBottom();
            mListLayout.setLayoutParams(lp); // <-- Calling setLayoutParams here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

How I create my animation `Animation a = new ExpandAnimation(initialHeight, targetHeight, v);` and the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/some_id_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    // layout

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/some_id_2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        // more layout

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/some_id_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            // even more layout

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/some_id_4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: why do you alter listview params, it has fill_parent for both width and height and it is the last item in the LinearLayout, which means after you/the system have measured the Views on top of the listview the remaining space is left for the listview, sounds lucid? try it, comment out the editting of the listview's params, and see if it works..

Comment: In addition to the animation I have a gesture listener with an overridden onFling method. The view doesn't behave nicely when I call the animation without setting the params for the linear layout.

Comment: okay Sir, but i was referring to the `LayoutParams` you set on the `Listview` itself i am saying comment that out, and maintain the `LayoutParams` on your `Linearlayout` and see if it helps